# Access Object3D loaded using OBJMTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building an application which allows users to upload 3D models in the obj/mtl format.  The admin displays a preview of what the loaded object will look like in our viewer.  I would like to provide controls for the user to set the initial y-position of the loaded object, and the initial z position of the camera.  I have the camera part worked out, but I'm having no luck with the y-position.  My code:

```
var obj3d;

loader.load( model_obj, model_mtl, function ( object ) {
    object.position.y = y_init;
    scene.add( object );
    render();

    obj3d = object;

    $('#initial_y').change(function() {
      obj3d.position.y = $(this).val();
    });

}, onProgress, onError );
```

The issue seems to be that once I am outside the `load` function, the reference to the `Object3D` is no longer available.  The code above gives a javascript error:

```
Cannot access property 'position' of undefined.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like it's a scope issue in the jQuery code.

Comment: Does the error refer to `object.position` or `obj3d.position`?

Comment: @gaitat The error is in reference to `obj3d.position`.  It shows up when the `#initial_y` input is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from @mrdoob led me to solving this myself.  My variable `obj3d` was indeed out of scope when the jquery callback was triggered.  I was able to resolve it by moving the variable declaration to the global scope.

Additionally, the reason I wasn't seeing the changes applied immediately in the three.js scene was because I needed to call the `render()` function.

```
$('#initial_y').change(function() {
    obj3d.position.y = $(this).val();
    render();
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that you need to use `obj3d = object.clone()`, because later your object is destroyed.